# Functional way to deal with null arguments

Tags: java, functional-programming, refactoring

I would like to write more functional java code in my work.
But how can I refactor something like bellow.

That code works, it has to to parse string like 100/100 and return pair of Integer.

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)(/)(\\d+)$");

public static Optional<Pair<Integer, Integer>> foo(String str) {
          var matcher = pattern.matcher(str != null ? str : "");
          return matcher.find() && matcher.groupCount() == 3 ?
            Optional.of(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)),
              Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3)))):
            Optional.empty();
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code had several typos so it couldn't have worked as posted.  Next time I recommend you just cut and paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
public static Optional<Pair<Integer, Integer>> foo(String input) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(input)
    .map(str -> pattern.matcher(str))
    .filter(matcher -> matcher.find() && matcher.groupCount() == 3)
    .map(matcher -> new Pair<Integer, Integer>(
      Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)),
      Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3))
    ));
}
```

It is best to always start with an `Optional` that way you avoid all null checks. Usually `Optional.of()` or `Optional.empty()` should be avoided for only making a final result:

- `Optional.of()` without any further operations is a code smell. It means you never had to do anything that required null checks to begin with. Yes, there are such cases but they are rare. Always look closely if you find such code.

  Normally, code should start with `Optional.of()` or `Optional.ofNullable()` and continue with `.map()` or other methods on it.
- `Optional.empty()` is similar. It means you never needed to even check for nullity, just returned an empty result. Well, there are some cases you can take this shortcut but usually the point of `Optional` is to start with *something* and operate on it. The result of the operations can then produce an empty result.

  Typically *correct* usage of `Optional.empty()` is done in the beginning - some check is made first and an empty optional is produced as [an early return](https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8). Be wary of returning `Optional.empty()` *last* or after you already have an `Optional` constructed.

Answer (score 1):

First, the pattern needs to be fixed to allow several digits and there's no need to use a separate group for `/` delimiter:

```java
pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)/(\\d+)$");
```

Next, it may be better to use `Optional.ofNullable` for the input parameter, and `Optional::flatMap` to handle `Optional<Pair>` returned after parsing the input string.

```
public static Optional<Pair<Integer, Integer>> foo(String str) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(str)
        .flatMap(s -> pattern.matcher(s)
            .results()
            .map(mr -> new Pair<>(Integer.valueOf(mr.group(1)), Integer.valueOf(mr.group(2)))) // Stream<Pair>
            .findFirst() // Optional<Pair>
        );
}
```

Tests:

```
System.out.println(foo("100/100"));
System.out.println(foo(null));
System.out.println(foo("abcd"));
```

Output:

```
Optional[100, 100]
Optional.empty
Optional.empty
```

---

Corrected Java 8 friendly solution by VLAZ could look like this:

```java
public static Optional<Pair<Integer, Integer>> foo(String str) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(str)
    .map(pattern::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::matches) // no need to use find() for the given pattern
    .map(matcher -> new Pair<>(
      Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1)),
      Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2))
    ));
}
```